# save user data to another model after user signup django

Tags: django, python-3.x

i have this portal where user can register as artists and i want to save those user on different artist category page after registration like if a user register as model it automatically saved on artist models so it can be fetch on artists page

artist models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

 class artist(models.Model):
     CHOICES = (
       (0, 'celebrities'),
       (1, 'singer'),
       (2, 'comedian'),
       (3, 'dancer'),
       (4, 'model'),
       (5, 'Photographer')
    )
    artist_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    artist_type = models.IntegerField(choices = CHOICES)
    artist_image = models.ImageField(upload_to= 'media')
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.artist_name
```

## Custom User Manager

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields ):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('user must have email address')
        now = timezone.now()
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(
            email = email,
            is_staff = is_staff,
            is_active = True,
            is_superuser = is_superuser,
            last_login=now,
            date_joined = now,
            **extra_fields
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self,email, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        user = self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

## custom user model

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    artist_choice = [
        (0, 'celebrities'),
        (1, 'singer'),
        (2, 'comedian'),
        (3, 'dancer'),
        (4, 'model'),
        (5, 'Photographer')

    ]
    Artist_Category = models.IntegerField(choices=artist_choice, null=True)
    Mobile_Number = PhoneNumberField(null=True)
    city = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_login=models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    country = CountryField()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD='email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=[]

    objects=UserManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%i/" % (self.pk)
```

views.py:

```
def talent(request, artist_type):
    artists = artist.objects.filter(artist_type = artist_type)
    context = {
             'aka': artists
    }
    return render(request, 'main_site/talent.html', context)
```

forms.py:

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    CHOICES = (
        (0, 'celebrities'),
        (1, 'singer'),
        (2, 'comedian'),
        (3, 'dancer'),
        (4, 'model'),
        (5, 'Photographer')
    )
    #Artist_Category = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
    #bio = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea,label = 'something about yourself')



    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email','name','Mobile_Number','Artist_Category','country','bio','city')
```

i have also added models in admin panel for artist creation

[image: admin artist]

and when user register its automatically get saved on this model

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to add user to artist model after signup

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an artist model instance when a user is created/registered. Consider, "Extending the Django User Model". You can do this using a One to One relationship or by using a Proxy User model.

An example of the One To One Model:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # Your artist fields
```

Then you can add some signals to update the artist model on user registration/changes.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_artist(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Artist.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_artist(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.artist.save()
```

By doing this, if the user is created or updated the relevant signal will be called, updating the artist model instance.